# Float basics in CSS

Tags: css, css-float, html

I know this is kind of a stupid doubt about floating CSS layout, but I can't find the answer anywhere.
I want to have a simple page, with a big red reactangle in the middle, and 2 blue squares within, one on each side of the rectagle.
I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="rectangle">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and then I have this css:

```
       #rectangle {
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #left {
            float: left;
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #right {
            float: right;
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

And this doesn't work, because the red rectangle doesn't adapt its height to cover the blue squares because they are floating I guess... 
The only way I know to solve this is adding a new

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

at the end of the rectangle div, with style

```
clear: both;
```

and I'm sure there should be a more elegant way to do this, isn't there?

Comment: use a "clearfix"(google) or `overflow:hidden;` on `#rectangle`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearfix?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: auto` to the #rectangle div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVJQN/

Answer (score 0):

add clear div

```
<div id="rectangle">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>​​​​​​

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
​
```